# Streaming TV on Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: hdmi

I was hoping to use a Pi Zero through an HDMI cord to watch TV using XFINITY Online. Would this work or will the Pi be too slow?

Answer (score 2):

It will likely be too slow as the Pi zero isn't the greatest at processing compressed video on the fly. This is due to the limited CPU and gpu power of the Pi zero. On a side note if you did not already know the Pi zero does not have an Ethernet jack or wifi built in. So to get network access you will need to use a USB adaptor which will further latencies.

Comment: even the R Pi 3  requires that you specially compile VLC to use the GPUs to get a good playback experience. I don't know if such a trick would help the Pi Zero, but I'm guessing not. Good luck to all.